# .htaccess how to redirect subdomain/folder to subdomain only

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to find an answer on different places, but I can't find the full solution for this.

I had a folder setup for a blog. Now we move to an subdomain setup. The redirect shown below works perfectly. The only thing that doesn't work is when the url is a subdomain combined with folder. that isn't redirected.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [L,QSA]
```

www.domain.com/blog/some-url-here is redirected to
blog.domain.com/some-url-here

When I try blog.domain.com/blog/some-url-here it returns a http-status of 200 and when I try to redirect I get a infinitive loop.

Is there a redirect that I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these rules on top of your other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/blog/([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://blog.domain.com/%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule !^blog/ blog%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```